# RegExp that matches any String containing "0-9" and "." and "-" and " "

Tags: regex

I need t check every line of a file for the following pattern:
- 14 Values seperated by an irregular number of spaces. 
- Values may be negative (-), decimal seperator is a dot followed by maximum one digit
- The line ends with several spaces

here is an example line:

```
10015 20100501  1    4.6    6.4    8.4   10.5   86.6    4.0   13.0    0.9    6.4    0.0 1007.2
```

Thanks!

Comment: FYI: Not all regex languages support capturing repeated groups, but it's not clear that's part of your requirements.

Answer (score 5):

This should do it:

```
/^(-?\d+(\.\d)?\s+){14}$/
```

Edit: Start and end tags as added by Gumbo.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regular expression:

```
/^(-?\d+(\.\d)? +){14}$/m
```

In multiline mode, the `^` and `$` match the start and end of the line respectively. `-?` is for the optional minus sign, `\d+(\.\d)?` is for the number with optional single decimal place, and  `+` (space plus `+`) is for the separating and trailing spaces. That pattern is then repeated exactly 14 time (`(…){14}`).